# Using VBscript and SSH

Tags: vbscript

New to VBscript and I'm trying to find a way to use VBscript to connect to a linux sever.  I was hoping it was as simple as the below code:

```
crt.Screen.Send "ssh" & ip & vbCr
```

Comment: Terminal Servers don't use the SSH protocol. What are you talking about?

Comment: You got me.  I'm trying to connect to a linux server using SSH with the command I stated above.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do once the connection is established?